# Google Chart Not Diplaying, Not showing any errors

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a Google Column Chart with the API. The data comes from a webservice as a JSON string that i parse and then maniplulate to add the data and then display the chart, like so.

```
var jsond = JSON.parse(response.d);
                var data = null;

                data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                for (var i = 0; i < jsond["cols"].length; i++) {
                    data.addColumn((jsond["cols"][i].type == 'number' ? 'number' : 'string'), null, jsond["cols"][i].id);
                }
                data.addRows(jsond["rows"].length);
                for (var i = 0; i < jsond["rows"].length; i++) {
                    data.setCell(i, 0, "'" + jsond["rows"][i].finmonth.toString() + "'");
                    data.setCell(i, 1, parseFloat(jsond["rows"][i].Target));
                    data.setCell(i, 2, parseFloat(jsond["rows"][i].Proposal));
                    data.setCell(i, 3, parseFloat(jsond["rows"][i].ContractTotal));
                    data.setCell(i, 4, parseFloat(jsond["rows"][i].Budget));
                    data.setCell(i, 5, parseFloat(jsond["rows"][i].flag));
                }

                var options = {
                    title: 'The road thus far',
                    vAxis: { title: "Totals" },
                    hAxis: { title: "Financial Month" }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
```

Now the problem is that it accepts the data and there are no errors that return. I have inspected the data after it is loaded in the datatable with `data.toJSON()` and it matches the way google prescribes the data should be. see below for my data, bear in mind that i have only added 1 datarow to the example below, there are 12 standard rows.

```
{"cols":[{"id":"finmonth","label":"","pattern":"","type":"string"},
{"id":"Target","label":"","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{"id":"Proposal","label":"","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{"id":"ContractTotal","label":"","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{"id":"Budget","label":"","pattern":"","type":"number"},
{"id":"flag","label":"","pattern":"","type":"number"}],
"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"'2013/1'","f":null},{"v":0,"f":null},{"v":37,"f":null},{"v":4696,"f":null},{"v":4733,"f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}]}],
"p":null}
```

So what am i missing? Because if i hard code test data in a javascript array the chart displays... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out nothing was wrong with my code.
The charts is within a jquery accordian and this is causing the issue.
To resolve this, render the charts only after the accordian has allready been "created" i.e.

```
$('div').accordion();
```

has been called.
They should then render correctly.